# Unable to start solr

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and I am trying to run solr but every time its giving me the error ERROR: java.exe not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe\bin. Please set JAVA_HOME to a valid JRE / JDK directory.

Comment: Provide more info: What is the value of environment variables JAVA_HOME and PATH. Also explain, how exactly are you launching solr.

Comment: It is solved I was pointing to wrong path in the JAVA_HOME, Thanks for the help!